# Parse pages being authenticated with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to parse an element from pages which can appear only after I am authenticated on the site.

The authentication page is /lws/wp-login.php

This is what I tried and it did not work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
agent.add_auth('http://example.com/lws/wp-login.php', 'login', 'pass')
agent.get('http://example.com/assimil-pour-mieux-connaitre-le-chinois/')   do |page|
  puts page.parser.css("p[style='text-align: center;'] strong")[0]
end
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have written would be authenticating you for basic authentication using username and password. If you want to create a session for your scrape, you'll need to submit the form on `/lws/wp-login.php` after filling it with Mechanize and then parse other pages. Be sure to store your cookie between the requests.

Comment: it seems that after sending the form mechanize is keeping cookies by himself, everything works, thanks